# How do I get Visual Studio 2015 to recognise the file path of a newly included header?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

[image]

[image]

In the std_lib_facilities.h is just a copy and paste from the code on his website and the code I have put in main.ccp is:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
cout << "Hello Worl/n";
return 0;
}
```

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding your original question, "how do I recognize the path of a newly added header"?

   a) The easiest way is to just add the .h file directly from your project:

   b) Alternatively, you can edit your project's include path:

   Project > Properties > VC++ Directories >
     <= add the directory with your new header(s) to the end of the existing path
2. Regarding your new question:  "Unable to start ... HelloWorld.exe":

   It sounds like you have compile errors, and the .exe never built.

   Run "Build > Build solution", and fix any errors.

Comment: thank you for your answer, which one is the one I should ad my header to out of [these](http://i.imgur.com/gzfXSLV.png)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this,

Go to the Change/Remove section from Uninstall programs tools in the Control Panel. From there, find Microsoft Visual Studio, right-click change. When the window pops up, select Repair. After doing this, see if it works.